# Does $\forall d \in \mathbb{N}\forall m \in \mathbb{N} \exists r\in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{4}r^d \leq m \leq \frac{1}{2}r^d$?

Tags: number-theory

In the book Random Walks and Heat Kernels on Graphs by M.T. Barlow, in the proof of theorem 3.26, that the isoperimetric inequality holds for $\mathbb{Z}^d$, the author states that we may choose and $r$ such that $\frac{1}{4} r^d \leq \mu(A) \leq \frac{1}{2} r^d$, with $A \subset \mathbb{Z}^d $ finite.

Here $\mu(A) := \sum_{x \in A}\sum_{y \in V} \mu_{xy}$ and we assume that $\mu_{xy} = 1$ if $x$ is a neighbour of $y$ and $0$ otherwise.

Since we later require that we can choose $d$-dim. cubes containing $r^d$ points I assume that $r\in \mathbb{N}$. However I do not see how one can prove that indeed for every finite subset $A$ such an $r$ exists.

I have already tried to choose such an $r$ via $\lceil (2\mu(A))^{1/d} \rceil$, where I however ran into problems with the exponent.

An alternative approach would be to show the possibly stronger statement that $\mathbb{N}\subset \bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{4}r^d,\frac{1}{2}r^d ]$, which again I do neither know how to prove or disprove.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the topic right.

Is it means that any given $d,m\in\mathbb N$ then we must be able to find $r\in\mathbb N$ that $\frac{1}{4}r^d\le m\le \frac{1}{2}r^d$?

If it is the case then we first observe that $r>1.$ By choosing $d$ large enough that $2^d>4m$ we have $$2>(4m)^{\frac{1}{d}}\ge r\ge (2m)^{\frac{1}{d}}\ge 1.$$
Thus, there is no $r\in\mathbb N$ satisfying the desired inequality $\Box$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Thus since indeed $\mu(A)$ can be chose as an arbitrary natural number, this does not hold.